# CString to LPCTSTR conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, cstring

I have a CString variable that i a need to convert to LPCTSTR(const char*) .I need this conversion so that i can use it as an argument in a function .

The CString look like :

```
CString sqlTemp = _T("INSERT INTO "+ sw1 +" (filename, "+ sw2 +") VALUE ("+ sw7 +","+ sw3 +" ) ");
```

It contains an query. The prototype of the function is :

```
int WriteBlob(LPCTSTR szSqlStat, LPCTSTR szFilePath)
```

So could you show me an exemple of how to convert to LPCTSTR ?
It may be trivial but i am a c++ beginner and i still get a hang of it.

Thanks .

Comment: please try this (LPCTSTR)(LPTSTR)sqlTemp to WriteBlog function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One method of conversion is like this:

```
CString str;

str = "Hello";

LPCSTR szTemp = (LPCSTR)(LPCTSTR)str;
```

Comment: Can you also explain as to why there are so many different formats (LPCTSTR, CString, char*, string, etc...) which are all basically the same? Or is there some difference I just cannot see?

Comment: fell string is an object so you can call methods on it unlike all the others. char* is basically an array of chars. Cstring is also an array of chars but they can take 2 bytes depending on the encoding. LPCTSTR is a pointer to a constant string, so you can't modify it.

Comment: " Cstring is also an array of chars" no, it's not.

Comment: @TamásSzelei It does point at an LPSTR / LPWSTR though.

Answer (score 0):

```
CString str; // the given string
CStringA strA(str); // a helper string
LPCSTR ptr = strA;
```

[Reference MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df7ae955-0c5d-408f-98d8-7349897114f3/cstring-to-lpcstr)