# Convert String^ in c# to CString in c++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, string, mfc, c-strings

I need a help on one question where I stuck while coding my app in `MFC`.

I am using `CLR` i.e `Common Language Runtime` in my application to integrate c# APIs.
but now I stuck on converting `System::String^` to `CString`.
I am not able to do that.

I am using Following code.

```
String^ csPass = gcnew String(strPassword.GetBuffer());
array<Byte>^ Value = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(csPass);
for (int i = 0; i < Value->Length; i++ )
{
csPass += String::Format( "{0:X2}", Value[ i ] );
}
```

now I want to convert `csPass` to `CString`.
Can any one help me on this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider reading [this MSDN thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx) about string conversions. Also, following discussions may be useful for you:

- [Convert CString to std::wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041241/convert-cstring-to-stdwstring)
- [Problem: How to convert CString into const char * in C++ MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493017/problem-how-to-convert-cstring-into-const-char-in-c-mfc)
- [Converting String to Cstring in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821491/converting-string-to-cstring-in-c)
- [CString to LPCTSTR conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620820/cstring-to-lpctstr-conversion)
- [Conversion of CString to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578522/conversion-of-cstring-to-char)
- [How to convert _bstr_t to CString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685819/how-to-convert-bstr-t-to-cstring)

With this material you can find out how to do it and even post own solution as an answer

Answer (score 6):

Got My answer.
Thanks for your support @Elliot Tereschuk.

I have gone through some references like

1. [How to: Extend the Marshaling Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531313.aspx)
2. [Overview of Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)
3. [For CString.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms908328.aspx)

and

include header files

```
#include <msclr/marshal_windows.h>
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
```

using Library
`using namespace msclr::interop;`

And finally My source code is.

```
String^ csPass = gcnew String(strPassword.GetBuffer());
array<Byte>^ Value = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(csPass);
for (int i = 0; i < Value->Length; i++ )
{
csPass += String::Format( "{0:X2}", Value[ i ] );
}

marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();

const char* str = context->marshal_as<const char*>(csPass);

csMyPass.Format(str);
```

`csMypass` is a `CString` type Variable.
Thank you for support.

Comment: I copied your codes to my project, but the compiler report that it cannot recognize this class: Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(csPass), do you know why? thank you!

Comment: @sunjinbo have u added the header files in your code. or refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596242/net-systemstring-to-utf8-bytes-stored-in-char

Comment: #include <msclr/marshal_windows.h>
is not required for my environment. I modified code a little:
  auto context = gcnew marshal_context();
  auto msgChars = context->marshal_as<const wchar_t*>(csPass);
  CString csMyPass(msgChars);

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, and it's much easier:

```
CString csPassAsCtring = CString(csPass)
```