# Hit webservice from mfc application and want to read user code return from webservice login method

Tags: c++, web-services, curl, mfc, libcurl

i am working with MFC application and i don't have knowledge about MFC because i am  Donet net developer .

i am trying to hit web service  which  coded in C# .web service has login method . when  i hit from MFC application  its work well . after check username and password login method return user code  .i want to read this user code in MFC application .

My MFC code is here

```
 CString clsLogin::login(CString username ,CString password)
     {

CString a1;
    a1.Format("%02X",""); szJson.Replace("byte1str", a1);
    a1.Format("%02X",""); szJson.Replace("byte2str", a1);
    a1.Format("%02X",""); szJson.Replace("byte3str", a1);
    a1.Format("%02X",""); szJson.Replace("byte4str", a1);
    a1.Format("%s",username);szJson.Replace("name1", a1);
    a1.Format("%s",password);szJson.Replace("pass1", a1);

curlcode = CURLE_OK;

char *posturi  = "myurl";
CURL *curl     = NULL;

curl = curl_easy_init();

 if(curl) {

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,              posturi);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,       szJson);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,    strlen(szJson));

   curlcode = curl_easy_perform(curl);


   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
} else {
    curlcode = CURLE_FAILED_INIT;
}


 return 0 ;
```

}

please help me

What should i add to this function to get return value from webservice method

C# code is Here

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public string CheckLogin(string data)
    {
```

//command  to database to check username and password

```
        return usercode;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please paste your C# code it will be more useful to understand problem?

Comment: i have add it please have a look

Comment: If I am not Wrong, you want to use database code used in `c#` to run for `MFC`?

Comment: yes, i am using database query to check user in c# method , method just return user code from c#  and i want to fetch this code in MFC app to check user .

Comment: Then Why don't you try `CLR` i.e. `Common Language Runtime` feature for this. Just by using C# library in your MFC application.

Comment: can you please explain process for this because its  first time i am using  MFC so i don't know how it use in MFC

Answer (score 0):

Its Better to use `CLR` i.e. `Common Language Runtime` feature of visual Studio.

Steps Are as Folows:

1. Change application setting to support `CLR`
   Go to ****Project -> Properties ->Configuration Properties-> General-> Common Language Runtime Support ->Change to `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)' ****
2. Add references any Library you want in your application.
   go to : **Project -> Properties ->Common Properties-> Add New Reference**
   Add references as "System.Web.Mvc" and "System.IO"
3. Add Following code to header :

   `using <System.dll>`
    `using namespace System;`
    `using namespace System::Web::Mvc;`
4. Use your C# code for database.

For further reference use following links:
1. [Use of HttepVerbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Hope It will help you

Comment: Thanks for help. can you please tell any option with curl  code

Comment: Is this ans helpful to you?

Comment: if i use  CLR  then  i have to make dll  for login process and then i will add this dll in project for use  .
am i right?

Comment: No, Its not the case. [See this Link Where I have used library in `C#` in my `MFC` Code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21060260/3110262)